# SAS 9.3 Proc Rank Issues (Rank/Sort Road Block)

Tags: sas, series, proc

I am working with a Data Set in this format:

```
Column 1 (What I Have),     Column 2 (What I need to see)
8   1
8   1
8   1
9   2
9   2
9   2
10  3
10  3
10  3
11  4
11  4
12  5
13  6
14  7
14  7
14  7
```

Attempting to use Proc Rank to Generate the Second Column
Code:

```
Proc Rank data=Have
out=Want
ties=low;
Var Column1; 
ranks Column2;
run;
```

The Output I get looks like this:

```
Column1 (What I Have)   Column2 (What I get)
8   1
8   1
8   1
9   199
9   199
9   199
10  415
10  415
10  415
11  613
11  613
12  823
13  1015
14  1222
14  1222
14  1222
```

Based on what I've read and heard the first dataset is what I expect my outcome to be.

Is there an error in the code or expectations that has lead to an output such as the one I am seeing?
Additionally is there a better way to generate a sequenced rank for a column of sequential numeric data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to let you know that I figured out how to use this.

The Key is in the Ties=(Low or High or Mean or Dense) Statement.

Here is the New Code that Works.

```
Proc Rank data=Have
out=Want
ties=dense;
Var Column1; 
ranks Column2;
run;
```

Now My Dataset Groups all like values and gives them the same count. Column 2 is generated with the proper values.   Documentation is here:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146840.htm#a003186386

Scroll to the bottom for features of Ties

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a Data Step assuming it is OK to sorted by Column1.

```
proc sort data=have;
 by column1;
run;

data want;
   set have;
    by column1;
    retain column2 ;
    if _n_ = 0 then
       column2 = 0;
    if first.column1 then
       column2 = column2 + 1;
run;
```

Comment: After reviewing my Statement I think I need to Clarify. I would like to Generate Column 2 It is not present in the data set.  And to answer your question yes We can (and do) sort on Column 1.

Comment: this creates column 2.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with an implied retain.

```
DATA WANT;
   SET HAVE;
    BY COLUMN1;
    IF _N_ = 0 THEN
       COLUMN2 = 0;
    IF FIRST.COLUMN1 THEN
        COLUMN2 + 1;
RUN;
```

Comment: After reviewing my Statement I think I need to Clarify. I would like to Generate Column 2.  And to answer your question @DomPazz yes We can (and do) sort on Column 1.